# How to add multiple .env files into nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js

I need something like .env | .env.development | .env.production
but seems @nuxt/dotenv is parsing just single .env file,
is there a way to use more env-files?

Answer (score 3):

you can use .env file like this :

```
yarn dev --dotenv .env.devevopment
```

look at this issue [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8331#issuecomment-727533175)